# Cannot add APT repositories

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I cannot add repositories. and when running sudo apt-get update. I get this error: I've tried removing them and re-adding

```
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: bionic repositories are for 18.04 LTS while disco repositories are for 19.04 . Are you sure you should be using repositories for multiple versions?

Comment: @user12031771 what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 19.04

Comment: I've also removed the repositories for 18.04, but the disco versions still show the same error